# Memory mapped file for OCaml's Hashtbl

Tags: ocaml, hashtable, memory-mapped-files

I am trying to do multiprocessing in OCaml, but if I do a do a fork the *virtual* memory doubles : the old process and the new process need to be both ``addressable''. This is a big problem to me, since it is not possible to fork a program if it uses more than half of the virtual memory (RAM+swap).

A solution to this problem would be to use memory-mapped files to store the large data-structures, so here comes my question:

Is there a simple way to put a hash table in a memory-mapped file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Netmcore_hashtbl`?

Comment: just looked at the ocaml weekly and saw : https://github.com/UnixJunkie/phashtbl

Comment: Did you run a full Gc cycle and compression before the fork? Because otherwise the next Gc compression will move your data causing all the shared pages to be unshared.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that!